# Is a finite sum of square roots of integers algebraic over the field of rational numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to prove it, but it doesn't work: Is the sum of square roots of integers algebraic over the field of rational numbers?

**Update**: In the discussion, we came to the conclusion that the sum of two algebraic numbers is algebraic. But how to prove that the root of an integer is algebraic?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133422/discussion-on-question-by-n2k-is-a-finite-sum-of-square-roots-of-integers-algebr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p$ and $q$ integers.

Let $x-\sqrt{p}-\sqrt{q}=0$

$x-\sqrt{p}=\sqrt{q}$

$x^2+p-q=2x\sqrt{p}$

$x^4+(p-q)^2+2x^2(p-q)=4x^2p$

$x^4-2x^2(p+q)+(p-q)^2=0$

Now given that $e=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...$ we have an example of a transcendental number resulting from the sum of infinite algebraics.

While the sum of any two integers' square roots is algebraic, I'm skeptical their infinite sum would be. Not sure how to prove it.

Comment: 1) What have we denoted for x?
2) We prove that infinite sum is algebraic in linked post to my question

Comment: I think those arguments address Finite Extensions. Extending to all integers' square roots would be an infinite extension, no?

Comment: How can this be proved?

Comment: Even if you ignore composite numbers, adding an additional extension extension for each prime will lead to an infinite field extension. 

$Q[\sqrt{2}]$ is algebraic. So is $Q[\sqrt{2}][\sqrt{3}][\sqrt{5}]$ ... for any finite number of terms, the sum of those terms is algebraic by the above. That's likely to break down for an infinite number of terms.